# Can Encrypt-then-MAC be used with session ticket resumption?

Tags: tls, authenticated-encryption

In **TLS 1.2**, say a session ticket is created for the current session (**Session Tickets** [RFC 5077](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5077)), and the current session uses the **Encrypt-then-MAC extension** [RFC 7366](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7366) (I.E. both client and server offered the extension in their Hello).

When resuming a session with that session ticket, is the use of Encrypt-then-MAC implied, or are the two features independently negotiated in each handshake?

Session tickets should prevent servers retaining any knowledge of past sessions, so if Encrypt-then-MAC is to be used in the resumed session, would it have to be explicitly advertised in either the hello extensions or be bundled into the ticket?

Beyond ETM, are there any prior extensions implied/included in the resumed session?